# SharePoint Online, How to Share Folder(Doc Library) to Anyone (anonymous users)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, anonymous-authentication, sharing, external-sharing

How to Share Folder(Doc Library) to Anyone (anonymous users) in SharePoint online?

Is it Available?

Thanks!

upd.: I found that since April 2017 we can [share **folders**](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13541985-external-folder-sharing-with-without-sign-in). Allowed "Anyone who have link" to view/edit, but get error:

[image]

**

### upd.:

** No, guys, it works. You need to disable "Lockdown" feature in 'Site collection features'. Closed